# libgdx: initialize core after download in android

Tags: android, download, libgdx, initialization

I download bitmaps from a server in the android package(AndroidLauncher.java). These bitmaps I pass to the core package(game-class) with interfacing(ImagesManager=Interface-Class) and there they will be rendered to the screen. The problem is, that the initialization of the core package is before the download is finished, so the app shuts always down. How can I code that it wait until the download is finished, before it initialize the game-class in the core package ?

AndroidLauncher.java

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    ImagesManager androidManager = new AndroidImagesManager();
    initialize(new game(androidManager), config);


        try {
            slide = 1;
            startDownloadTask(slide);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: if i pass bitmap located on the phone, my code works. The problem is just by not waiting for the download before initialize game-class.